# Having an issue with Spring-boot's built-in logger when deploying app to tomcat server

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, tomcat

I am building a Spring Boot application with a MongoDB database and I am running into an issue when the application is deployed to the server and starts logging. I have done some digging on the internet and all the answer I am getting is that I need the following maven dependency and to do an install. I have done that and unfortunately the issue still remains.

I am currently using MongoDB version 4.4.11 and Spring-boot version 2.6.1

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.myproject</groupId>
        <artifactId>backend</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>pe</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>myproject Backend Pe</name>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.myproject</groupId>
            <artifactId>core</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-properties-migrator</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
                 
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <start-class>com.myproject.mobileplatform_backend.app.Application</start-class>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <warName>pe</warName>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.3.2</version>
                    <executions>
                    
                        <!-- installs node modules -->
                        <execution>
                            <id>npm install</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>exec</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                            <configuration>
                                <executable>npm</executable>
                                <arguments>
                                    <argument>install</argument>
                                </arguments>
                                <workingDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/frontend</workingDirectory>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
    
                        <!-- builds frontend -->
                        <execution>
                            <id>angular build</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>exec</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <phase>compile</phase>
                            <configuration>
                                <executable>ng</executable>
                                <arguments>
                                    <argument>build</argument>
                                    <argument>--prod</argument>
                                    <argument>--deploy-url</argument>
                                    <argument>dist/</argument>
                                </arguments>
                                <workingDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/frontend</workingDirectory>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>                        
                    </executions>
                    
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

Readout from localhost..log:

```
14-Jan-2022 11:41:57.058 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
14-Jan-2022 11:42:15.809 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log 1 Spring WebApplicationInitializer detected on classpath
14-Jan-2022 11:42:24.270 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
14-Jan-2022 11:42:32.293 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart Exception starting filter [errorPageSecurityFilter]
 java.lang.AbstractMethodError
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:285)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4590)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5233)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:752)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:630)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1842)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

14-Jan-2022 11:42:32.323 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
```

Errors when deploying to server:

```
Exception in thread "cluster-ClusterId{value='61dde73d6257ab22798db558', description='null'}-localhost:27017" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ch/qos/logback/classic/spi/ThrowableProxy
        at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.LoggingEvent.<init>(LoggingEvent.java:119)
        at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.buildLoggingEventAndAppend(Logger.java:419)
        at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.filterAndLog_0_Or3Plus(Logger.java:383)
        at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.info(Logger.java:595)
        at com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.SLF4JLogger.info(SLF4JLogger.java:76)
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.logStateChange(DefaultServerMonitor.java:266)
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:164)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ThrowableProxy]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForClassLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1301)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1158)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1119)
        ... 8 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ThrowableProxy]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1311)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForClassLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1299)
        ... 10 more
    Exception in thread "cluster-ClusterId{value='61dde7416257ab22798db559', description='null'}-localhost:27017" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ch/qos/logback/classic/spi/ThrowableProxy
        at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.LoggingEvent.<init>(LoggingEvent.java:119)
        at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.buildLoggingEventAndAppend(Logger.java:419)
        at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.filterAndLog_0_Or3Plus(Logger.java:383)
        at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.info(Logger.java:595)
        at com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.SLF4JLogger.info(SLF4JLogger.java:76)
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.logStateChange(DefaultServerMonitor.java:266)
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:164)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Exception in thread "cluster-ClusterId{value='61dde7416257ab22798db55a', description='null'}-localhost:27017" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ch/qos/logback/classic/spi/ThrowableProxy
        at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.LoggingEvent.<init>(LoggingEvent.java:119)
        at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.buildLoggingEventAndAppend(Logger.java:419)
        at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.filterAndLog_0_Or3Plus(Logger.java:383)
        at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.info(Logger.java:595)
        at com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.SLF4JLogger.info(SLF4JLogger.java:76)
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.logStateChange(DefaultServerMonitor.java:266)
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:164)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Second Error:

```
Exception in thread "cluster-ClusterId{value='61e1a55b4e705712d5c92121', description='null'}-localhost:27017" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mongodb/internal/connection/DecimalFormatHelper
    at com.mongodb.connection.ServerDescription.getRoundTripFormattedInMilliseconds(ServerDescription.java:1041)
    at com.mongodb.connection.ServerDescription.getShortDescription(ServerDescription.java:1016)
    at com.mongodb.connection.ClusterDescription.getShortDescription(ClusterDescription.java:327)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.BaseCluster.updateDescription(BaseCluster.java:245)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SingleServerCluster.publishDescription(SingleServerCluster.java:125)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SingleServerCluster.publishDescription(SingleServerCluster.java:116)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SingleServerCluster.access$200(SingleServerCluster.java:41)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SingleServerCluster$DefaultServerDescriptionChangedListener.serverDescriptionChanged(SingleServerCluster.java:107)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultSdamServerDescriptionManager.updateDescription(DefaultSdamServerDescriptionManager.java:127)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultSdamServerDescriptionManager.update(DefaultSdamServerDescriptionManager.java:81)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:165)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [com.mongodb.internal.connection.DecimalFormatHelper]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForClassLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1301)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1158)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1119)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [com.mongodb.internal.connection.DecimalFormatHelper]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1311)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForClassLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1299)
    ... 14 more
Exception in thread "cluster-ClusterId{value='61e1a55c4e705712d5c92122', description='null'}-localhost:27017" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mongodb/internal/connection/DecimalFormatHelper
    at com.mongodb.connection.ServerDescription.getRoundTripFormattedInMilliseconds(ServerDescription.java:1041)
    at com.mongodb.connection.ServerDescription.getShortDescription(ServerDescription.java:1016)
    at com.mongodb.connection.ClusterDescription.getShortDescription(ClusterDescription.java:327)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.BaseCluster.updateDescription(BaseCluster.java:245)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SingleServerCluster.publishDescription(SingleServerCluster.java:125)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SingleServerCluster.publishDescription(SingleServerCluster.java:116)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SingleServerCluster.access$200(SingleServerCluster.java:41)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SingleServerCluster$DefaultServerDescriptionChangedListener.serverDescriptionChanged(SingleServerCluster.java:107)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultSdamServerDescriptionManager.updateDescription(DefaultSdamServerDescriptionManager.java:127)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultSdamServerDescriptionManager.update(DefaultSdamServerDescriptionManager.java:81)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:165)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "cluster-ClusterId{value='61e1a5544e705712d5c92120', description='null'}-localhost:27017" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mongodb/internal/connection/DecimalFormatHelper
    at com.mongodb.connection.ServerDescription.getRoundTripFormattedInMilliseconds(ServerDescription.java:1041)
    at com.mongodb.connection.ServerDescription.getShortDescription(ServerDescription.java:1016)
    at com.mongodb.connection.ClusterDescription.getShortDescription(ClusterDescription.java:327)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.BaseCluster.updateDescription(BaseCluster.java:245)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SingleServerCluster.publishDescription(SingleServerCluster.java:125)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SingleServerCluster.publishDescription(SingleServerCluster.java:116)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SingleServerCluster.access$200(SingleServerCluster.java:41)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SingleServerCluster$DefaultServerDescriptionChangedListener.serverDescriptionChanged(SingleServerCluster.java:107)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultSdamServerDescriptionManager.updateDescription(DefaultSdamServerDescriptionManager.java:127)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultSdamServerDescriptionManager.update(DefaultSdamServerDescriptionManager.java:81)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:165)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Do you have logback-classic-1.1.11.jar in the classpath? As a side note, version 1.1.11 is marked as vulnerable (as you can see [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic)).

Comment: @Olivier I have since removed the version number from the declaration in the pom file so the project is now using 1.2.7 by default.

Comment: And do you get logback-classic-1.2.7.jar? Is it present in the `lib` directory of your webapp in Tomcat?

Comment: you have not assembled your build bundle, war, correctly. it's not issue with logging but your war building, but since you haven't provided your build script or more details about your build process we can't know what it is.

Comment: Those errors appear **after** your application has already stopped or more probably failed to start. What is the **first** error? If it is a listener error, it might be in `localhost.<date>.log`.

Comment: I have updated the question with my project's pom file as well as a readout of the localhost.log file

Comment: There is a known bug for the issue which happens in Spring Boot 2.6.1. You can upgrade the Spring Boot to 2.6.2. I believe it should fix.

Comment: Arent you using MongoDb dependency in your pom? Try using spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb in pom

Comment: #1 Did you solve your problem? You have several errors. Try to **stabilize the localhost before deploy it** on a server. #2 enable verbose log with `debug=true` on spring boot application.properties. #3 How are you running the app on your localhost? #4 Are your local workspace on windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the main issue you are facing is related to the error presented in `localhost.log`:

```
14-Jan-2022 11:42:32.293 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart Exception starting filter [errorPageSecurityFilter]
 java.lang.AbstractMethodError
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:285)
```

The error has to do with the inability of Tomcat to successfully initialize [ErrorPageSecurityFilter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.6.0/api/org/springframework/boot/web/servlet/filter/ErrorPageSecurityFilter.html).

This filter tries to prevent unauthorized access to the application error page.

It was introduced in Spring Boot 2.6.0.

The filter was initially meant as a Servlet 4.0 [`HttpFilter`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/servlet/http/HttpFilter.html).

As you can see in the [history of changes of the component](https://github.com/Artur-/spring-boot/commits/29a33ebe4ada23b3b34f8421347d0c7acd5d5278/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/web/servlet/filter/ErrorPageSecurityFilter.java), that fact had been the cause of different changes in order to provide support for containers in which the Servlet 4.0 version is not supported.

These changes has been documented in different issues, mainly [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/pull/28902), although there are other related ones [1](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/28790) [2](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/29135) [3](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/28854).

Basically, as you can check in the aforementioned history of the component, they [first](https://github.com/Artur-/spring-boot/commit/e6b5be900ae27c4aa59bbf6db6c5f85ff0c0fc1e#diff-a12b56ffe1b71fd7fc8fc13c27f031b00797d0dd4a4df661fd064bae4cff9ffa) refactored the filter to implement `Filter` instead of extending `HttpFilter`.

In the Servlet 4 version the `Filter` interface provides default methods implementation for both [`init`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/servlet/Filter.html#init-javax.servlet.FilterConfig-) and `destroy`. To mimic this behavior and make it Servlet 3.x compatible, in a later change, [the Spring developers provided a no-op implementation of `init`](https://github.com/Artur-/spring-boot/commit/29a33ebe4ada23b3b34f8421347d0c7acd5d5278#diff-a12b56ffe1b71fd7fc8fc13c27f031b00797d0dd4a4df661fd064bae4cff9ffa) in the `ErrorPageSecurityFilter` itself.

As you can see in the change log, this last issue was fixed in [Spring Boot 2.6.2](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/releases/tag/v2.6.2).

On application startup, Tomcat finds and tries initializing the `ErrorPageSecurityFilter` filter but probably you are using [a version of Tomcat still not Servlet 4 version compliant](https://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html) and, according to the version of Spring Boot you are using, 2.6.1, this filter provides no `init` implementation, and that is the reason why Tomcat complains about the `AbstractMethodError`.

In order to solve the problem, please, consider update your application dependencies to Spring Boot 2.6.2.

I think once updated, the different deployment related errors will go away, they seem to be caused by threading or class loading issues when Tomcat terminates abruptly the application as a consequence of the `ErrorPageSecurityFilter` related error.

Answer (score 0):

This may be because of incompatible version of spring-data and db-driver dependency. Please check if the version of db-driver is compatible with the provided spring-data dependency.

Try this version:
SpringBoot 2.5.6 for MongoDB 4.4.11

If SpringBoot 2.6.1 if required try:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

for mongo dependency.

Answer (score 0):

It seems this issue:

https://gitmetadata.com/repo/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/29135

You might force the use of tomcat 9 with the following property in your pom:

```
<properties>
    <tomcat.version>9.0.55</tomcat.version>
<properties>
```

though tomcat embedded version for spring-boot 2.6.1 should be 9.0.55